# Drop down menu with sub category using R and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinybs

I want to create a dropdown menu with sub-categories using R - how is a sub-category supposed to be introduced?

```
`if (interactive()) {  
 ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
            c("HTML Code tester", "Font Styler", "CSS3 Generator", "Box Shadow", "Border Radius"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}`
```

Actual output: [Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXEC9.png)
Desired Output: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgfsI.png)

How do I create something like what's in desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit different context but you may want to check out `menuSubItem` in `shinydashboard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
 selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
              list("HTML Code tester",
                   "Font Styler", 
                   "CSS3 Generator"=c( "Box Shadow", "Border Radius")))
```

Comment: It's true. I don't think "base" bootstrap supports multilevel dropdown menus. For that, it has to be extended.

Comment: Right, it just adds a header to the menu items. Thanks @yeedle